# cin and cout operator error C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am doing an assignment for school and at school we use codeblocks for our IDE, but I wanted to use visual studio at home. The problem is when I run my program on visual studio I continue to get an operator error on my cin and cout but only before a string. I tried #include  and while the error lines went away when I build I get the same error before. I am new to C++ and rather confused any help is appreciated. 
picture of code below

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9srQ.jpg

Comment: Please include your code in the question (not a screenshot but the actual code). Tell us what exactly is the error and on which line does it happen.

Comment: For learning, I recommend unchecking the "Use precompiled headers" option when making a project. They won't benefit your learning projects and just add an extra thing to worry about.

Answer (score -1):

The `#include <string>` you tried would be correct.

Your main problem is the `#include "stdafx.h"`. It's a [Precompiled header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precompiled_header). Visual studio puts it in by default although it isn't required. It has to be the first include if you use it:

> Visual C++ will not compile anything before the #include "stdafx.h" in the source file, unless the compile option /Yu'stdafx.h' is unchecked (by default); it assumes all code in the source up to and including that line is already compiled.

Just put it as the first #include (or get rid of it completely) to fix your issue. Then the rest should start working normally.